# Joining more than 1 column using Merge join transformation in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssms, msbi

I have came across scenarios where we have 1 column join in Merge join transformation , but i am not able to find out a option where i would specify 2 columns to join in MergeJoin transformation. Is there a property or some other way i would achieve this.

Could anybody help.

Comment: include your tried code to get respnse?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to join two tables with multiple conditions then you must
sort them [image]

See above I had sorted tow columns(for two tables) and in merge transformation I joined them.

---

vote if it helps you